# Using mutate to interpolate based on subset of columns in dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm stuck figuring out how I can use mutate to do a linear interpolation based on a subset of columns. I can use the approx function in a for loop and get what i'm looking for but am getting the error `Error in xy.coords(x, y) : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'.`

```
df <- data.frame(Jan = rep(0,10), Feb = 1:10, Mar = 2*(1:10), Apr = 3*(1:10), val=c(3,6,2,12,4,8,3,5,22,14))
x <- c(31,60,91,121)
```

The following *for* loop works:

```
for(i in 1:dim(df)[1])
{
    df$m[i] <- approx(cbind(0, df[i,1:4]), x, df$val[i])[2]
}
```

I'm trying to achieve the same result with mutate

```
s<-mutate(df, m=approx(cbind(0, df[,1:4]), x, val)[2])
```

but the above line of code gives me the error message. Any help in explaining where I'm going wrong?

Comment: The for loop example throws an error: `Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rowwise` to perform the interpolation on each row

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(m = approx(c(Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr), x, val)[[2]])
```